# How to get selected rows in vb6 Datagrid

Tags: vb6

I have a vb6 application I am supporting and we need to add a method that grabs data from multiple selected rows in a databound grid.

Can anyone point me in the direction to loop through the datagrid to find out what rows are selected?

Answer (score 3):

its very simple just you need to do is

```
dim numberofRow as integer
numberofRow = datagrid.row
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some sample code here: 
http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=64111&lngWId=1